# C# Working with private double functions to calculate distance

Tags: c#

I have been newly introduced to the world of C# coding. Currently, I am working in program that will calculate the average speed using the total distance traveled and the total hours traveled and that outcome will be multiplied by the time to get from NY city to MIAMI to get the distance from NY city to MIAMI. I have placed four `textBoxes` on the form and one `button` to do the calculation.

I am needing help building the functions. For example, in order to calculate velocity: velocity = distance/time. How would I put that information in the proper format inside the CalculateVelocity() function?

**4 TextBoxes and their labels(this is where the user will inpu their data):**

```
Starting Mileage
Ending Mileage
Total Driving Time 
Time from NY city to MIAMI
```

**Code- Functions I am using:**

```
 private double CalculateVelocity()
    {
        //Calculate Velocity
    }

    public double GetTime()
    {
            //Get Time
            return GetTime;
    }

    private double CalculateDistance(double velocity, double time)
    {
        //Calculate Distance
    }

    private double DisplayResults(double velocity, double time, double distance)
    {
        //Display Results
    }

    private double ClearTextboxes()
    {
        //Clear textboxes
    }

    // Property to GetTime
   private double GetTime
        {
            get
            {
                // variable to hold time
                double time = double.MinValue;

                // Safely parse the text into a double
                if (double.TryParse(tbTime.Text, out time))
                {
                    return time;
                }

                // Could just as easily return time here   
                return double.MinValue;
            }
            set
            {
                // Set tbTime
                tbTime.Text = value.ToString();
            }
        }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Calculate and display result in a label
    }
```

Comment: So you want to take the Start Mileage and End Mileage to get the distance and then use the time input to calculate the velocity?

Comment: @LukeHennerley, when the button is pressed, an average speed will be calculated using the total distance traveled and the total hours travled, and that will be multiplied by the time to get from NY city to MIAMI to get the distance from NY city to MIAMI. The label report the speed, time, and the distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CalculateVelocity` should look something like this:

```
private double CalculateVelocity()
{
     double time = GetTime(); //assuming you have set up GetTime()
     double distance = endingMileageBox - startingMileageBox;
     return distance/time; 
}
```

where `endingMileageBox` is the value from the ending mileage textbox, and `startingMileageBox` is the value from the starting mileage textbox.

---

Per your comment, here's what `CalculateDistance` should look like:

```
private double CalculateDistance(double velocity, double time)
{
    //note that this assumes the units match up. If not, you'll need to do some conversions here
    return velocity * time;
}
```

}

Comment: +1 this is perfect. I have not set up `GetTime()`. Any sugestion how to set up `GetTime()`?

Comment: Well, assuming `tbTime` is populated, you actually may want to just do `double time = GetTime;` instead. If you're gonna make `GetTime` a public property, you don't really need a function for getting time. I would really suggest making the `GetTime`property private and then making `GetTime()` look like this: `public double GetTime(){return GetTime;}`

Comment: Alright I edited my answer according to you help. I am now getting an ambiguity error between `GetTime()` and `GetTime` when declaring this `public double GetTime(){return GetTime;} `. WHy is that?

Comment: @charliecodex23 oh, right. Well, that's because c# doesn't know whether to return the property `GetTime` or the function handle `GetTime`. Try making the property one lowercase.

Comment: Thank you! One last thing, if you dont mind. Can you show me how to calculate the distance for the function `Calculate_Distance`?

Comment: @charliecodex23 see my edit. Note that because `CalculateDistance` is marked as private, the only place that you'll have access to it is within the same class. If you need to use it elsewhere, you'll need to either make it public or do something like `public double Calculate_Distance(double velocity, double time){return CalculateDistance(velocity,time);}` Note that for this one, I used `Calulate_Distance` instead of `CalculateDistance` to avoid an ambiguity error.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the arguments you need, and do the parsing from text box (as you have shown you know how to) can before calling the functions which should go like this:

```
private static double CalculateVelocityMPH(double distanceMiles, double timeHours) 
{ 
    return distanceMiles / timeHours;
}
```

Worth while picking and specifying the units like I have as post fixes.

Then when parsing the time text box, use `TimeSpan.Parse` and then `.TotalHours` to call the method with.